# How to Replace string data with another string data using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I want to replace string data with another string data.

I have tried to do so with the following code.

```
$('#btnchkProduct').click(function () {
    var  stringfirst="hi this is first data";
    var  stringsecound="this is another data";

    var finaldata = string.replace(stringfirst , stringsecound );
    alert(finaldata );
});
```

Comment: remember to use `/g` to replace all , ex: `mystring.replace(/oldstring/g,'newstring')`

Comment: Where does the `news` variable come from? And the `string` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#btnchkProduct').click(function() {
  var stringfirst = "hi this is first data";
  var stringsecound = "this is another data";

  var finaldata = stringfirst.replace(stringfirst , stringsecound );
  alert(finaldata);
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery is just a wrapper to javascript .
String replacement functions are there in javascript core , you  can use that directly

```
var str="Visit Microsoft!";
var n=str.replace("Microsoft","W3Schools");
```

Refer [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can Simply use

```
$('#btnchkProduct').click(function () {
    var  stringfirst="hi this is first data";
    var  stringsecound="this is another data";

    var finaldata = stringsecound.replace(stringsecound, stringfirst);
    alert(finaldata );
});
```

the second string will be replaced by first string